# Wordpress - Unlink empty category links

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to generate two category lists in Wordpress:

```html
<h2>Headline 1</h2>
<article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <ul class="columns">
    <?php echo wp_list_categories('title_li=&hide_empty=0&exclude=1,54,55'); ?>
  </ul>
</article>
<h2>Headline 2</h2>
<article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <ul class="columns">
    <?php echo wp_list_categories('title_li=&hide_empty=0&include=54,55'); ?>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Is there anyway to unlink the categories that hasn't got any posts? I still want them to be visible in the list, but not as links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (get_category('17')->category_count > 0) echo "<a 
href=\"".get_bloginfo('home')."/category/news/\">Blog</a>"; ?>
```

You can only get the link only that category who has posts otherwise you will not get the link on category name but category name will be shown you in the list.

Comment: Hm, can you elaborate what you mean? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: instead of 17 you can pass the category id so, it will check that category has posts or not. if that category has posts more than 0 then only it will print the link of the post.